# CSS transition on modal img size

Tags: jquery, css

I have simple responsive modal. One problem. I can't understand where i should  set transition for images for trigger it  on prev-next button. I want the modal window resize with transition when button is triggered. When i use transition on .modal-content img it doesn't work
Code for images

```
.modal-content img {
display:block;
position:relative;
width:100%;
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
transition:width 500ms linear, height 500ms linear;
}



.button-click {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
   }
```

Code for button

```
$('.btnModal-right').click(function(){
    clicked.next().find('img').addClass('button-click').trigger('click');
});

$('.btnModal-left').click(function(){
    clicked.prev().find('img').addClass('button-click').trigger('click');
});
```

Could you point me to the right direction?
Thank you!

Comment: you have no CSS for any transitions

Comment: I know. That's hy i ask where i should set transition? I tried to set width and height transition on .modal-content img and then create another class with width:100% and height:auto for use it in addClass metod but it doesn't work for me.